# How can we handle MSSQL raiseerror in VB.net code behind using sqlcommand?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have written one store procedure which raise error on same specific condition. when i call this store procedure using vb.net code using sqlcommand I m not able to catch RAISEERROR

**Store Procedure**

```
Create sp_UPDATE
as 
begin


    IF @QTY > @ReqAlloQty
    BEGIN
         RAISERROR('Product Quantity should not be more than Required qty.',16,1)        
         goto EXITWITHERROR  
    END             

end
```

**VB.NET**

```
 Try
    m_commDBcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
 Catch ex As Exception
 Finally
 End Try
```

exception is not raised when store procedure condition is matched.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.errors.aspx

Comment: Maybe more of a code-sample might encourage people to answer? At the moment it seems that you're not processing anything in the exception handler so it'll be ignored by the calling application? Also I would suggest (as a first step) implementing a try-catch-print-throw clause in your sp_UPDATE to ensure that you're actually throwing an exception back to the application?

Answer (score 0):

Add a return statement after raiserror:

```
RAISERROR('Product Quantity should not be more than Required qty.',16,1);
RETURN;
```